# Selecting based on string in a list C# LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

So I have a class named event which contains a List ListofInvites, It has email addresses of different user(another class which has a emailid property), now I want to select all the  events based on whether the listofinvites string contains that specific email

I have tried this but i'm getting an error

```
var userEmailID = this.User.Identity.GetUserName();


var events = this.dataBase.Events
       .OrderBy(e => e.DateAndTime)
       .Where(e => e.listOfInvites.Contains(userEmailID))
       .Select(EventViewModel.ViewModel);
```

Yeah sorry  I was in a hurry last night when i posted this

So I have this event class

```
public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        this.IsPublic = true;
        this.DateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
    [Key]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }

    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OtherDetails { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> listOfInvites { get; set; }

    public string  InviteList { get; set; }
}
}
```

the error i'm getting is

`System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'listOfInvites' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'`

Comment: Please provide the Invite class, EventViewModel.ViewModel code, and also the error message.

Comment: I have edited it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Event` entity, you are declaring a `IEnumerable<string>` property (`listOfInvites`) while list of primitive types is not supported in Entity Framework and since this property is not mapped to a database column you cannot use it in a where expression.
You need to create another entity (therefore table) for `ListOfInvites` with a foreign key to the `Event` entity.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code will solve your issue.

var events = dataBase.Events.Where(p => p.listOfInvites.Contains(userEmailID)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your classes, but I'm guessing you have a list of some class named `Event` in your database, each of which has a `List<Invite>` property, and then an `EmailId` `string` property on each one of those `Invite` instances.
If that's the case, since your `EmailId` is not a property in the `Event` itself, you'll have to iterate through each event's `List<Invite>` to get the `EmailId` associated with it.
The relations I'm guessing are: **Many** events in your database; **many** invites on each `Event`; and **one** `EmailID` on each `Invite`.

Following this assumptions, I would do this:

```
var events = this.database.Events.Where(e => e.ListOfInvites.Any(i => i.EmailId.Contains(userEmailId))).ToList();
```

So, from each of the events on the (assummed) `List<Event>` on your database, we'll search through every invite in it's `ListOfInvites` property (that's the `e => e.ListOfInvites` part), looking for any invite where it's `EmailId` matches the one we passed, i.e.: `i => i.EmailId.Contains(userEmailId)`. 
This `var` will then become a `List<Event>` representing all the events to which our user is invited.

Comment: I have edited my question can you take a look at it now?